# How to select only the p.value >0.05 after performing Shapiro-Wilk test in Rstudio?

Tags: r

How can I select only the p.values >0.05 after performing Shapiro-Wilk test in Rstudio.
I have a dataframe of 92 columns and 300 rows, so I don't want to do this 1 by 1.

I did manage to do the shapiro.test on my data en this resulted in 92 statistic and p.value one for each column. some have p.value < 0.05 and some >0.05. 
Is there a way to select only the p.value > 0.05 for further analysis?

Thx, Barry

Comment: I recommend providing example code and data. This helps us see what you approach you are trying and the structure of your data. Specifically in this case I wanted to know what "mange to do the shapiro-test on my data" meant, because the structure of your output is important for what solution will work.

Comment: consider reading https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless ...

Answer (score 2):

Your question didn't provide sample data, so I'll use the `attitude` data in R.

Based on what you write, I interpret that you applied over the dataset and ran `shapiro.test()` on each column. My answer assumes this approach.

> I did manage to do the shapiro.test on my data en this resulted in 92 statistic and p.value one for each column

If you use an `lapply()` the output will be a list of results for Shapiro-Wilks tests, one result for each column. All we need to do is subset this list based on p-value.

```
# example data
attitude

# run the Shapiro-Wilks test on each column, save the output
results <- lapply(attitude, shapiro.test)

#subset to just results where p > 0.05
subset_vector  <- sapply(results, function(x) x$p.value > .05)
results_subset <- results[subset_vector]

# alternatively, do the subset on one line
results[sapply(results, function(x) x$statistic > .05)]
```

As you can see, this approach uses an `sapply()` to check whether the p-value is > 0.5 for each column's output. The resulting named vector has a `TRUE` for each column you want to use for more analyses. In the example code, this is the `attitude$critical` column, which is left out of the `results_subset` object.